# StackOverFlow error

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, stack-overflow, dbgrid

I have a `DBGrid` and use it to get data into a `Array`. But as soon as I press the button to do this procedure I get a StackOverFlow error ? Here is the Code I use :

```
iRy := 0;

iCol := DBGrid.Columns.Count;

sTest := DBGrid.Columns[0].Field.AsString;

While sTest <> '' do
  begin
   for k := 1 to iCol do
    begin
     arrData[iRy+1,iCol] := DBGrid.Columns[iCol].Field.AsString;
    end;
   Inc(iRy);
   DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.Next;
   sToets := DBGrid.Columns[0].Field.AsString;
  end;
```

I am using Delphi 7 .

Comment: Does not fit to StackOverFlow error (perhaps a sideeffect of invalid access here arrData[iRy+1,iCol] or here DBGrid.Columns[iCol].), but Columns and dynamic Arrays are Zerobased (for k := 0 to iCol-1 do). 
`Not Dataset.EOF` condition is missing in the While

Comment: sToets := DBGrid.Columns[0].Field.AsString;, you wanted **sTest** := DBGrid.Columns[0].Field.AsString;, your loop will go to loop to infinity or until you fill the entire stack(this happens first)

Comment: Can you fix your typo and see if you still get the same error

Comment: What data type is `arrData`? If it is a static array declared as a local variable it has to be < 1 Mbyte in size to fit on the default stack. A two dimensional array can easily reach this limit, producing a stack overflow as soon as the procedure is entered

Comment: P.S.: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500433/i-get-an-error-estackoverflow-when-creating-packed-struct-in-delphi-7-0?rq=1 for a more complex example of this.

Answer (score 0):

When does `sTest` change?

A stackoverflow is caused by running out of memory on the stack.  This While loop will go forever.  You need to set sTest to something other than '' in the loop, or perhaps you meant to use an if statement.

Comment: a simple endless loop will not cause a stackoverflow, in combination with "endless" incrementing iRy the access to arrData[iRy+1,iCol] might corrupt the stack ...

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues:

- You never assign anything else to `sTest` after you initialize it (before the loop)
- You're continually looping over the same record, because there's no `Next`, and no change to `sTest`. Once you start the loop, you stay there.
- You're going past the end of the `Columns`, because you're going to `Column.Count`, and the last valid index is `Column.Count - 1`

Try this instead, to see if it's more what you're after:

```
iRy := 0;
sCol := DBGrid.Columns.Count - 1;

// I'm not sure why you're not putting this in the first (0 index) element
// of arrData - is that intentional?
sTest := DBGrid.Columns[0].Field.AsString;

while (sTest <> '') and (not DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.Eof) do
begin
  for k := 1 to iCol do
    arrData[iRy, iCol] := DBGrid.Columns[iCol].Field.AsString;
  DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.Next;
  Inc(iRy);
  sTest := DBGrid.Columns[0].Field.AsString; 
end;
```

Comment: Please always use begin - end blocks, using a for loop without a begin end block is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: @Toby: There's no need for a `begin..end` for that loop; it executes a single line of code (assignment to the array). If a second line is added, so is the `begin..end`.

Comment: The begin ... End doesn't get added automatically with the second line hence the bug!  Can you honestly tell me you've never caused a bug like this?

Comment: @Toby: Yes, I can honestly say I've never caused a bug like this, because I **know** to add the `begin..end` when I go from a two-line `for` loop to one that has more lines. It's not rocket science. It's also the reason I format my code the way I do, precisely so you can see where begin and end are needed. There's no point in typing two extra lines of code every time you have a two-line `for` loop.